# Incrementing the for loop (loop variable) in scala by power of 5

Tags: scala, loops

I had asked this question on [Javaranch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/517192/Scala/Incrementing-loop-loop-variable-scala), but couldn't get a response there. So posting it here as well:

I have this particular requirement where the increment in the loop variable is to be done by multiplying it with 5 after each iteration. In Java we could implement it this way:

```
for(int i=1;i<100;i=i*5){}
```

In scala I was trying the following code-

```
var j=1
for(i<-1.to(100).by(scala.math.pow(5,j).toInt))
{
  println(i+" "+j)
  j=j+1
}
```

But its printing the following output:
1 1
6 2
11 3
16 4
21 5
26 6
31 7
36 8
....
....

Its incrementing by 5 always. So how do I got about actually multiplying the increment by 5 instead of adding it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's first explain the problem. This code:

```
var j=1
for(i<-1.to(100).by(scala.math.pow(5,j).toInt))
{
  println(i+" "+j)
  j=j+1
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var j = 1
val range: Range = Predef.intWrapper(1).to(100)
val increment: Int = scala.math.pow(5, j).toInt
val byRange: Range = range.by(increment)
byRange.foreach {
  println(i+" "+j)
  j=j+1
}
```

So, by the time you get to mutate `j`, `increment` and `byRange` have already been computed. And `Range` is an *immutable* object -- you can't change it. Even if you produced new ranges while you did the `foreach`, the object doing the `foreach` would still be the same.

Now, to the solution. Simply put, `Range` is not adequate for your needs. You want a geometric progression, not an arithmetic one. To me (and pretty much everyone else answering, it seems), the natural solution would be to use a `Stream` or `Iterator` created with `iterate`, which computes the next value based on the previous one.

```
for(i <- Iterator.iterate(1)(_ * 5) takeWhile (_ < 100)) {
  println(i)
}
```

**EDIT: About Stream vs Iterator**

`Stream` and `Iterator` are very different data structures, that share the property of being *non-strict*. This property is what enables `iterate` to even exist, since this method is creating an infinite collection<sup>1</sup>, from which `takeWhile` will create a *new*<sup>2</sup> collection which is finite. Let's see here:

```
val s1 = Stream.iterate(1)(_ * 5) // s1 is infinite
val s2 = s1.takeWhile(_ < 100)    // s2 is finite
val i1 = Iterator.iterate(1)(_ * 5) // i1 is infinite
val i2 = i1.takeWhile(_ < 100)      // i2 is finite
```

These infinite collections are possible because the collection is not *pre-computed*. On a `List`, all elements inside the list are actually stored somewhere by the time the list has been created. On the above examples, however, only the first element of each collection is known in advance. All others will only be computed if and when required.

As I mentioned, though, these are very different collections in other respects. `Stream` is an `immutable` data structure. For instance, you can print the contents of `s2` as many times as you wish, and it will show the same output every time. On the other hand, `Iterator` is a mutable data structure. Once you used a value, that value will be forever gone. Print the contents of `i2` twice, and it will be empty the second time around:

```
scala> s2 foreach println
1
5
25

scala> s2 foreach println
1
5
25

scala> i2 foreach println
1
5
25

scala> i2 foreach println

scala>
```

`Stream`, on the other hand, is a `lazy` collection. Once a value has been computed, it will *stay* computed, instead of being discarded or recomputed every time. See below one example of that behavior in action:

```
scala>     val s2 = s1.takeWhile(_ < 100)    // s2 is finite
s2: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> println(s2)
Stream(1, ?)

scala> s2 foreach println
1
5
25

scala> println(s2)
Stream(1, 5, 25)
```

So `Stream` can actually fill up the memory if one is not careful, whereas `Iterator` occupies constant space. On the other hand, one can be surprised by `Iterator`, because of its side effects.

(1) As a matter of fact, `Iterator` is not a collection at all, even though it shares a lot of the methods provided by collections. On the other hand, from the problem description you gave, you are not really interested in having a collection of numbers, just in iterating through them.

(2) Actually, though `takeWhile` will create a new `Iterator` on Scala 2.8.0, this new iterator will still be linked to the old one, and changes in one have side effects on the other. This is subject to discussion, and they might end up being truly independent in the future.

Comment: What's the difference between using Stream.iterate and Iterator.iterate?

Comment: You missed the index in that final example.

Comment: @Kevin Weird, I had made the same error on REPL and corrected it there, but somehow I copied the version with error to the answer. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: @Daniel: only because I almost did the same myself, then went and added the `zipWithIndex` variant

Comment: @ziggystar Iterator is what you usually want, even when you think you want a stream.  The biggest obvious difference is that you can go back and read a stream again, and it won't need to recalculate values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and also more information provided. Learn't a lot in this particular post. Thanks Daniel. I would simply need to iterate and not store the values. So I think I can use Iterator.

Comment: @Daniel Then is there a collection that can be traversed multiple times but doesn't cling onto the values like Stream does?

Answer (score 10):

In a more functional style:

```
scala> Stream.iterate(1)(i => i * 5).takeWhile(i => i < 100).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 5, 25)
```

And with more syntactic sugar:

```
scala> Stream.iterate(1)(_ * 5).takeWhile(_ < 100).toList
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 5, 25)
```

Comment: slightly cleaner: `Stream.iterate(1)(5*) takeWhile (100>=) toList`

Comment: @Kevin Slightly shorter, not necessarily cleaner except, perhaps, for Haskellites. :-)

Comment: @Daniel Shorter, with fewer full stops (and brackets).  So, perhaps, less clear for the Clojurites :)

Comment: @Kevin I do like the infix notation, though you _know_ that `toList` at the end of the line might well cause trouble inside a program, unless the next next is blank or starts with a keyword. It is the partially applied functions that I think can often detract more than it enhances legibility.

Comment: @Daniel yeah, that part's definitely a matter of taste.  Given the number of underscores that can so easily enter a lot of Scala programming, my personal preference is to cull them on a semi-regular basis...

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin. Coming from a OOP background- The first one is understandable for me :). With more FP programming adding syntactic modifications should become familiar.

Comment: As I just wanted to iterate, I might as well use an Iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a simple while-loop would do?

```
var i=1;
while (i < 100)
{
   println(i);
   i*=5;
}
```

or if you want to also [print](http://ideone.com/pfLEx) the number of iterations

```
var i=1;
var j=1;
while (i < 100)
{
   println(j + " : " + i);
   i*=5;
   j+=1;
}
```

it seems you guys likes functional so how about a [recursive solution](http://ideone.com/lx5L1)?

```
@tailrec def quints(n:Int): Unit = {
  println(n);
  if (n*5<100) quints(n*5);
}
```

Comment: while the above is not functional, it is still much more efficient.

Comment: The recursive solution is good, by tagging it with `@tailrec` is recommended, to make sure it can be optimized.

Comment: Thanks, annotated it for tail recursion.

Comment: The tail-recursive variant is also likely to be the fastest single-threaded solution on this page.

Comment: Not sure if it's due to additional args in the benchmarks, but the loop seems to be slightly faster: http://www.copypastecode.com/51675/

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Thanks for spotting the error...  it should of course be power, not multiply:

Annoyingly, there doesn't seem to be an integer `pow` function in the standard library!

Try this:

```
def pow5(i:Int) = math.pow(5,i).toInt
Iterator from 1 map pow5 takeWhile (100>=) toList
```

Or if you want to use it in-place:

```
Iterator from 1 map pow5 takeWhile (100>=) foreach {
  j => println("number:" + j)
}
```

and with the indices:

```
val iter = Iterator from 1 map pow5 takeWhile (100>=)
iter.zipWithIndex foreach { case (j, i) => println(i + " = " + j) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(0 to 2).map (math.pow (5, _).toInt).zipWithIndex
res25: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((1,0), (5,1), (25,2))
```

produces a Vector, with i,j in reversed order.