# Rewrite 'for' loop from Java to Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

I need to convert some Java code to Scala. I have such source. How to rewrite it in Scala? Question may be simple. But it match harder then for(i <- 1 until 10) {} examples in documentation.

```
for (int i = password.length(); i != 0; i >>>=1)
  { some code }
```

King regards,
Alexey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it to be as fast as possible--which I am assuming is the case given the shift operation--then you should use a while loop:

```
var i = password.length()
while (i != 0) {
  // some code
  i >>>= 1
}
```

It's one of the few cases where Java is more compact than Scala given the same operation.

You could also use tail recursion:

```
final def passwordStuff(password: Password)(i: Int = password.length): Whatever = {
  if (i != 0) {
    // Some code
    passwordStuff(password)(i >>> 1)
  }
}
```

which will compile into something of the same speed as the while loop (in almost every case, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

If you seek for exotic functional way you can write something like this:

```
Stream.iterate(password.length)(i => i >>> 1).takeWhile(0!=)
```

It lazily performs the following actions: takes password length as initial value, applies `{ => i >>> 1 }` to it, passes it to the next iteration, applies ... passes, ...

Then I've scoped computation, limiting it to only thoose values that are not equals to 0.

Answer (score 1):

`i >>>=` 1 is equivalent to `i /= 2` for positive integers.

Combining this knowledge with the answers to [Incrementing the for loop (loop variable) in scala by power of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194075/incrementing-the-for-loop-loop-variable-in-scala-by-power-of-5) you should be set.

Comment: Thank you very much for link. I added it to my bookmarks. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

didnt know the >>>= operator. Let's try to be a little more functional, foreach takes a function A => Unit, in this case A is Int

```
def breakdownBy2(from:Int):List[Int] = if(from == 0) Nil else List(from) ++  breakdownBy2(from/2)
breakdownBy2(passoword.length).foreach(println(_))
```